# How to save PDF in Application asp.net (EVO generated PDF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am working with EVO pdf DLL.
I have done all the functionality related to pdf.
Is anyone knows how to save THE generated pdf instead of downloading.

Here is my code I am able to save that file to my location but **txt** format file is getting generated.

This IS my Code

Please correct me if i am doing wrong.

```
 httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename='" + purchase_order_number + "'.pdf; size={0}", pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));

 pdfConverter.SavePdfFromUrlToFile(host + "/pdf-purchase-order/Default.aspx/?in=" + purchase_order_number + "&vid=" + vendor_id + "&wid=" + WarehouseAddress, Server.MapPath("../backup111/"+purchase_order_number+".pdf"));
```

Comment: [tag:asp.net] or [tag:asp-classic], which is it?

Comment: LukeH, from Cardiff, United Kingdom I need your help sir, I am able to save my pdf file to desktop but it is saved in text file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html to create the pdf you can use the following

```
SavePdfFromHtmlStringToFile(html, "PATH_TO_FILE");
```

We really need more info to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you successfully generated pdf, that means you are able to see that pdf on server, then you can save it on client machine by this code

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; 
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test_PDF.pdf"); 
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Test_PDF.pdf")); 
 Response.End();
```

[Here](http://www.evopdf.com/evopdfdemo/HtmlToPdfFeaturesDemo.aspx) is a complete demo.

Comment: but Test_PDF.pdf HOw do i get that file name

Comment: As you are able to see that pdf, it must be having some name, why dont you use that name?

Comment: I dont know the name of the pdf file

Comment: See edited answer, it has useful link, go through that and revert to me if you have any problem

Comment: Nope frnd I am not getting the name of the pdf

Comment: Before converting it you must write httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=HtmlToPdfFeatures.pdf; size={0}", 
                        pdfBytes.Length.ToString())); where HtmlToPdfFeatures.pdf will be ur filename

Comment: Please check the code I ahve edited the code Please correct me if i am wrong i am very much near to the solution

Comment: The link I have mentioned in my answer, go through that. One line will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using evohtmltopdf.dll you have this function:

```
pdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile("html url to convert","file_path.pdf");
```